# Как пофиксить Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: unable to write file?

Tags: php, html

Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: unable to write file /home/admin/web/atlas-craft.ru/public_html/recloud/modules/cabinet/templates/templates_c/wrt63b97aa4ab4281_44617396 <-- thrown in /home/admin/web/atlas-craft.ru/public_html/recloud/modules/cabinet/engine/libs/template/sysplugins/smarty_internal_runtime_writefile.php on line 60

Answer (score -1):

Поставьте права на папку и файлы 777 и тогда будет нормально

```
sudo chmod -R 777  /home/admin/web/atlas-craft.ru/public_html/recloud/modules/cabinet/templates/
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/admin/web/atlas-craft.ru/public_html/recloud/modules/cabinet/engine/libs/template/
```

Да и вообще в целом надо вам пересмотреть права на папки проекта в целом. Какие-то из них нуждаются в 777, какие-то в 755. Также папки нуждаются в установки владельца для папки и для группы. Это тоже важно. Конечно, если работать чисто у себя и для себя, то можно поставить на `public_html` полностью 777 и не париться. Но обычно в проектах придётся чуть поназначать

Comment: минус за вредный совет: `Поставьте права на папку и файлы 777`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin почему же вредный? У фреймворков различных это даже требование поставить 777 на папку с template или view. К тому же эта папка не является секретной, где происходит бизнес логика. Это чисто отображение данных...... А в другом случае я указал что следует это сделать только если работа ведётся только у себя и нигде более. Так что минус абсолютно безосновательный

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin как пример: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDLL3.png  это инициализация проекта на фреймворке yii2. Где эти самые папки (и не только) ставятся 777, в ином случае работать корректно не будет

Comment: 1. пример относится к коду, удалённому ещё в 2015-м году (я не поленился склонировать репозиторий и посмотреть). 2. yii — это же веб-фреймворк, правильно? я не верю, что он настолько переусложнён, что требует запуска нескольких экземпляров веб-сервера, работающих от имени разных пользователей. пользователь явно только один. следовательно, раз вы пишете, что без доступа на запись другим пользователям в нём что-то может не работать — разработчики очень криворуки. значит, и пример их кривых «решений» не стоит и гроша.

Comment: ну а совет следовать кривым «решениям» — вреден. чтд.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin  **1.** код  https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/init   .... 2020 последнее изменение. что вы там склонировали и что смотрели - неизвестно...... **2.** При разработке допустимо менять некоторые вещи, при развёртывании на prod'е - уже другие требования... Ровно по причине упрощения процесса и облегчения жизни при разработке - в браузере например советуют отключать кэширование (disable cache), потому что при разработке это только лишний геморрой и добавляет кучу проблем..... с продом - нет.. так что ваши слова всё так же бестолковые

Comment: 1. смотрел https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2. 2. ещё раз повторю свою мысль, но другими словами: если с файлами и каталогами работают процессы, принадлежащие только одному пользователю, то давать другим пользователям права на запись в эти файлы — абсолютно бессмысленно, и является лишь дырой в безопасности, не более и не менее. и если без этого, как вы пишете, «работать корректно не будет» — это значит, что разработчики здесь просто облажались. потому и ссылаться на их практику — моветон. 3. если вы до сих пор так и не поняли смысл мною написанного, то я умываю руки.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin вообще пофигу было изначально))